Fullcalendar with vue using eventResize and eventDrop, work when dragging time or changing time
I use editable = true and use eventDrop and eventResize to be able to move times, locally it works perfectly, but when I play for production (npm run build), when dragging the time, the screen completely locks the browser tab.
I'm using vue3 with vuetify and the fullcalendar and typescript library.
import type {
    CalendarApi,
    CalendarOptions,
    EventApi,
    EventSourceFunc,
} from "@fullcalendar/vue3";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import listPlugin from "@fullcalendar/list";
import scrollGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/scrollgrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import resourceTimeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid";
import resourceTimeline from "@fullcalendar/resource-timeline";

 eventResize({ event: resizedEvent }) {
        debugger;
        if (resizedEvent.start && resizedEvent.end){
            alert.confirm('Deseja mesmo alterar este horário?').then(res=>{
                if(res.isConfirmed){                        
                    updateEvent(extrairDadosEventos(resizedEvent));
                }
            })
        }
     },
eventDrop({ event: droppedEvent }) {
            debugger;   
            alert.confirm('Deseja mesmo alterar este horário?').then(res=>{
                if(res.isConfirmed){                                            
                    updateEvent(extrairDadosEventos(droppedEvent));
                }
            })      
         },

I've already tried changing the way the eventDrop and eventResize functions are called and also setting a 300ms debbounce, but it still keeps crashing.
